# Assigning Itemscope Attribute a Value in Rich Snippet

Tags: html, rich-snippets

So we are using some rich snippets and they use the html5 markup scheme.

Our problem is the itemscope attribute doesn't have a value.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

This cause our old products html validation to fail because it thinks it's an empty tag.  Does google and markup rules work the same if you assign it a value of 1 like so.

```
<div itemscope="1" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

It's a work around for now until we can properly update our validation methods but that is a farther out project.

So basically is there a proper syntax to make this still valid for Googles Rich Snippet rules, html5 and older validation engines prior to html5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This answer is basically copied from [Peter Murray](http://dltj.org/article/schema-org-invalid/), specifically these [two](http://dltj.org/article/schema-org-invalid/#comment-146961) [comments](http://dltj.org/article/schema-org-invalid/#comment-146968).)

The HTML5 spec allows for [boolean attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes) with a value of an empty string or the attribute name:

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So either this:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

or this:

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

is valid HTML5.

To be sure that Google recognizes `itemscope="itemscope"` correctly, he (Peter Murray) created an [example page](http://dltj.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/schema-event-html5.html) and ran it through [Google's rich snippet validator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). From the [results](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdltj.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F06%2Fschema-event-html5.html&view=), you can see that Google picked up the data (an Event item) correctly.